# Getting error: Could not extract PID of 'io.appium.settings' from ps output - During testing

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I am running Android automated tests on IntelliJ with Appium. Tests run fine on Windows, on Linux, however, I get this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not extract PID of 'io.appium.settings' from ps output: PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND

I am getting desperate and can't find solution online.

These are my caps:

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities()
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android")

        //mandatory capabilities
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Phoenix")
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android")
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.4")
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator1")

        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout",1800)// trying this to let videos play w/o interrupt
        //other caps
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", LoginAppPackageName)
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", LoginAppActivityName)
        //capabilities.setCapability("dontStopAppOnReset",true)
        //capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true)
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 1000000)

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities)
        app = new AbstractScreen(driver){}

    }
```

Here's what Appium is saying:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.15.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.jht.mainapp","appActivity":"com.jht.mainapp.ActivityLandingPage","newCommandTimeout":1000000,"platformVersion":"4.4","automationName":"UiAutomator1","platformName":"Android","device":"Android","deviceName":"Phoenix"}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appPackage":"com.jht.mainapp","appActivity":"com.jht.mainapp.ActivityLandingPage","newCommandTimeout":1000000,"platformVersion":"4.4","automationName":"UiAutomator1","platformName":"Android","device":"Android","deviceName":"Phoenix"},null,null]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1572031645875 (14:27:25 GMT-0500 (CDT))
[Appium] Appium v1.15.1 creating new AndroidDriver (v4.20.0) session
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "appPackage": "com.jht.mainapp",
[BaseDriver]   "appActivity": "com.jht.mainapp.ActivityLandingPage",
[BaseDriver]   "newCommandTimeout": 1000000,
[BaseDriver]   "platformVersion": "4.4",
[BaseDriver]   "automationName": "UiAutomator1",
[BaseDriver]   "platformName": "Android",
[BaseDriver]   "device": "Android",
[BaseDriver]   "deviceName": "Phoenix"
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   device
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: b0b926b4-e442-4394-91f6-275f6ef60907
[ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     /home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"0d2331d4e6fdf318","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '4.4'
[ADB] Setting device id to 0d2331d4e6fdf318
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 4.4.2
[ADB] Setting device id to 0d2331d4e6fdf318
[AndroidDriver] Using device: 0d2331d4e6fdf318
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[ADB] Setting device id to 0d2331d4e6fdf318
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 19
[ADB] Device API level: 19
[AndroidDriver] App file was not listed, instead we're going to run com.jht.mainapp directly on the device
[AndroidDriver] Checking whether package is present on the device
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell pm list packages com.jht.mainapp'
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Using 'apkanalyzer' from '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer'
[ADB] Starting '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer' with args ["manifest","print","/tmp/.mount_Appium7SIr0g/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk"]
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('2.14.2' >= '2.14.2')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/tmp/.mount_Appium7SIr0g/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell 'pidof --help > /dev/null; echo $?''
[ADB] Using ps-based PID detection
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell ps'
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[ADB] Running '/home/dqetester/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 0d2331d4e6fdf318 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1572031652986 (14:27:32 GMT-0500 (CDT))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not extract PID of 'io.appium.settings' from ps output: PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
[MJSONWP]     1 0          0:07 /init
[MJSONWP]     2 0          0:00 [kthreadd]
[MJSONWP]     3 0          0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
[MJSONWP]     5 0          0:01 [kworker/u:0]
[MJSONWP]     6 0          0:00 [watchdog/0]
[MJSONWP]     7 0          0:00 [khelper]
[MJSONWP]     8 0          0:00 [kworker/u:1]
[MJSONWP]    13 0          0:00 [suspend]
[MJSONWP]   203 0          0:00 [sync_supers]
[MJSONWP]   205 0          0:00 [bdi-default]
[MJSONWP]   207 0          0:00 [kblockd]
[MJSONWP]   240 0          0:00 [khubd]
[MJSONWP]   248 0          0:00 [irq/461-pfuze]
[MJSONWP]   279 0          0:00 [ipu1_task]
[MJSONWP]   280 0          0:00 [ipu1_task]
[MJSONWP]   307 0          0:00 [usb_wakeup thre]
[MJSONWP]   309 0          0:00 [otg_switch]
[MJSONWP]   313 0          0:00 [usb_wakeup thre]
[MJSONWP]   326 0          0:00 [kswapd0]
[MJSONWP]   328 0          0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
[MJSONWP]   330 0          0:00 [crypto]
[MJSONWP]   355 0          0:00 [mxcfb0-vsync-pr]
[MJSONWP]   910 0          0:00 [kapmd]
[MJSONWP]   953 0          0:00 [f_mtp]
[MJSONWP]   958 0          0:00 [file-storage]
[MJSONWP]   994 0          2:07 [kinteractiveup]
[MJSONWP]  1004 0          0:00 [vpu_wq]
[MJSONWP]  1007 0          0:00 [galcore workque]
[MJSONWP]  1008 0          0:00 [galcore daemon ]
[MJSONWP]  1009 0          0:00 [galcore daemon ]
[MJSONWP]  1023 0          0:00 [binder]
[MJSONWP]  1052 0          0:04 [mmcqd/0]
[MJSONWP]  1053 0          0:00 [mmcqd/0boot0]
[MJSONWP]  1054 0          0:00 [mmcqd/0boot1]
[MJSONWP]  1070 0          0:00 /sbin/ueventd
[MJSONWP]  1845 0          0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p3-]
[MJSONWP]  1846 0          0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
[MJSONWP]  1847 0          0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p5-]
[MJSONWP]  1848 0          0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
[MJSONWP]  1849 0          0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p7-]
[MJSONWP]  1850 0          0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
[MJSONWP]  1851 0          0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p8-]
[MJSONWP]  1852 0          0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
[MJSONWP]  1856 0          0:00 [cfg80211]
[MJSONWP]  1870 0          0:01 [mcu_srv]
[MJSONWP]  1872 0          0:00 [goodix_wq]
[MJSONWP]  1876 0          0:00 /sbin/healthd
[MJSONWP]  1877 0          0:00 /system/bin/bin/sh
[MJSONWP]  1878 1000       0:00 /system/bin/servicemanager
[MJSONWP]  1879 0          0:00 /system/bin/vold
[MJSONWP]  1880 0          0:02 /system/bin/netd
[MJSONWP]  1881 0          0:00 /system/bin/debuggerd
[MJSONWP]  1882 1000       0:04 /system/bin/surfaceflinger
[MJSONWP]  1883 0          0:00 zygote /bin/app_process -Xzygote /system/bin --zygote --s
[MJSONWP]  1884 1019       0:00 /system/bin/drmserver
[MJSONWP]  1885 1013       0:00 /system/bin/mediaserver
[MJSONWP]  1886 1012       0:00 /system/bin/installd
[MJSONWP]  1887 1017       0:00 /system/bin/keystore /data/misc/keystore
[MJSONWP]  1888 0          0:00 /system/xbin/su --daemon
[MJSONWP]  1898 1023       0:00 /system/bin/sdcard -l -t4 /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated
[MJSONWP]  1904 2000       0:01 /sbin/adbd
[MJSONWP]  2114 1000       1:13 system_server
[MJSONWP]  2170 0          0:00 [flush-179:0]
[MJSONWP]  2332 10002      0:03 {d.process.media} android.process.media
[MJSONWP]  2344 10018      0:01 {putmethod.latin} com.android.inputmethod.latin
[MJSONWP]  2354 10035     13:29 {om.jhtp.workout} com.jhtp.workout
[MJSONWP]  2365 10033      0:00 {emanagerservice} com.jhtp.updatemanagerservice
[MJSONWP]  2379 10004      0:01 {ndroid.systemui} com.android.systemui
[MJSONWP]  2389 10037      0:12 {licationservice} com.jhtp.applicationservice
[MJSONWP]  2400 10029     10:40 {jhtp.halservice} com.jhtp.halservice
[MJSONWP]  2413 10031      0:00 {p.loggerservice} com.jhtp.loggerservice
[MJSONWP]  2430 10030      0:00 {settingsservice} com.jhtp.settingsservice
[MJSONWP]  2439 10038     28:53 {tamatrixservice} com.jhtp.datamatrixservice
[MJSONWP]  2451 10042      0:00 {nalyticsservice} com.jhtp.analyticsservice
[MJSONWP]  2463 10039      0:01 {htp.dapiservice} com.jhtp.dapiservice
[MJSONWP]  2476 10034      0:02 {m.jht.splashapp} com.jht.splashapp
[MJSONWP]  2563 0          0:00 watchdogd 30 30
[MJSONWP]  2765 1000       0:00 {ndroid.settings} com.android.settings
[MJSONWP]  2808 0          0:00 [wl_event_handle]
[MJSONWP]  2813 0          0:04 [dhd_watchdog_th]
[MJSONWP]  2814 0          1:51 [dhd_dpc]
[MJSONWP]  2815 0          0:01 [dhd_rxf]
[MJSONWP]  2818 1010       2:04 /system/bin/wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/d
[MJSONWP]  3198 10036      0:08 com.jht.mainapp
[MJSONWP] 14131 1014       0:00 /system/bin/dhcpcd -ABKL -f /system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd.con
[MJSONWP] 16538 0          0:03 [kworker/0:2]
[MJSONWP] 16870 0          0:01 [kworker/0:0]
[MJSONWP] 17241 0          0:00 [kworker/0:1]
[MJSONWP] 17367 2000       0:00 ps
[MJSONWP]     at ADB.getPIDsByName (/tmp/.mount_Appium7SIr0g/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/adb-commands.js:1261:11)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 7231 ms - 4345
[HTTP]
```

Comment: Update the appium and try. Check this link: https://discuss.appium.io/t/failed-to-start-appium-session-error-could-not-extract-pids/21525/2

Comment: @SadhaNanda thank you for your reply. Appium is already at the latest version 1.15.1. Node version 12.12.0